# Error starting the ClickOnce xbap application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, iis, clickonce

I'm trying to publish a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) browser application to an [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) server.

Currently, everything is set, and I can reach the website from all computers in the local network. However, after pressing `Run`, the application only works on the server PC. This is the only computer that has the option to run the application.

I'm guessing something is off with the manifests or something. I have no clue where to look for. What should I do or check?

Comment: What do the other computers show? do they throw an exception or something?

Comment: @HighCore The problem is, it says something went wrong and that's it! No explanation, nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the issue that the application isn't *installing* on other computers or that the application isn't *running* on other computers?

If it is not *running* on other computers I'd enable fusion log messages (by setting registry keys) - see [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net).

Most often the issue is a missing assembly (the Server machine has something installed, most likely to the GAC that is not included in your manifest).  The way to fix this is to set CopyLocal=true on any missing assembly references.